# Why is my object printing to the page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run my rails server in chrome, at the end of the unordered list, the object hash is printing to the page. I am not sure why this is happening. Here is my show.html.erb -

```
<h1><%= current_user.email %>'s Cars</h1>

<ul>
<%= current_user.cars.each do |car| %>
<li><%= car.color %></li>
<li><%= car.make %></li>
<li><%= car.model %></li>
<li><%= car.year %></li>
<button class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_car_path(car) %>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to 'Delete', car,  :data => {:confirm 
=> "You Sure?", :method => :delete}  %></button>
<%end%>
</ul>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <button class="btn btn-default"><%=link_to "Add a car", 
new_user_car_path(current_user)%></button>
<%end%>
```

Comment: can you show the output of the page?

Comment: can't figure out how to add a screenshot in the comments at the moment, but on the html page, this is printed after the unordered list -

Comment: [#<Car id: 3, make: "new", model: "car", year: 0, color: "4", user_id: 1, created_at: "2018-02-19 21:31:50", updated_at: "2018-02-19 22:04:20">]

Comment: Could it be the `<%=` in `<%= current_user.cars.each do |car| %>` ? The equals sign means it should output the result of that ruby code, and `each` outputs the array being iterated over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are itreating that hash and printing it at the same time

remove the # from this line`<%= current_user.cars.each do |car| %>`
 to following `<% current_user.cars.each do |car| %>`